# Finding inactive session files in Django

Tags: python, django

I use django sessions with file system backend. I have set SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE to True. So my current session becomes invalid when the browser closes. But the session file created remains.

I want to delete all inactive/invalid files. How can I find these files?

Answer (score 1):

Note that this setting means that the cookie (on the client side!) is deleted after the browser is closed. The session on the server remains until it has expired.

Sessions are stored in the database backend of the Django site. If you want to clear all open sessions, check out [Clearing the session table](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-table).

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to use

```
python manage.py cleanup
```

for deleting this files.

Comment: yepp, it's a good practice to restart memcache once a week. Oh, wait... there are also file-based sessions... does anyone actually use them?

Comment: Yes, people use file-based sessions.  They're the easiest session backend to set up.

Answer (score 1):

The way to handle this, as of Django 1.5 and later, is to use the new "clearsessions" command available from django-admin.py and manage.py.  It clears out file-based sessions, which the "cleanup" command didn't do.  As an example usage, you could set up a cron job to regularly run:

```
django-admin.py clearsessions
```

(make sure the cron job can access the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable)

For more information, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#clearsessions).